# How to remove folding marks in margin when using scrlttr2

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I am writing a letter, with the following MWE (non-working, really):

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{x}
\opening{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This code produces some lines in the margin to indicate where to fold or crease the letter (foldmarks).  (The `x` is added to avoid compiler errors.)[image: Letter with foldmarks]

How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 3):

Simply adding the KOMA-option

```
\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off}
```

to the preamble will remove them.